# Does Bayes theorem hold for variance?

Tags: variance, random-walk, bayes-theorem

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$
I am trying to find $\Var[A\mid B]$ of a random walk when $A < B$. I was wondering whether i can apply the Bayes theorem which says that

> $P[A\mid B]$ = $\dfrac{P[B\mid A]P[A]}{P[B]}$

to the variance such that

> $\Var[A\mid B]$ = $\dfrac{\Var[B\mid A]\Var[A]}{\Var[B]}$

Comment: What does var[A I B] mean, they are not random variables but events.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz This is standard notation for the conditional variance and is used in information theory, for example.